# How to add head to snake in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in programming things, So I wanted to start good projects with a snake game with canvas, Now I make one but it does not work well. I have a snake but I have a problem while adding it to the head.

```js
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
drwhd.fillStyle ="blue";
for (var i = 0; i < snakeTrail.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(
      snakeTrail[i].x * tileSize,
      snakeTrail[i].y * tileSize,
      tileSize,
      tileSize
    );
}

drwhd.fillRect(
    snakeHead[k].x * tileSize,
    snakeHead[k].y * tileSize,
    tileSize,
    tileSize
);
```

I tried these codes for the head . There is not an error but it should draw body with white and head with a blue. It draws all blue. I hope someone can fix this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<title>Snake</title>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<div id="score"></div>
<div id="highscore"></div>

<script>
    var score = 0;
    var highScore = 1;
    var gridSize = (tileSize = 20); // 20 x 20 = 400
    var nextX = (nextY = 0);
    //var jj = "https://i.hizliresim.com/p24p2r.png";

    // TISSS YILAAAN 
    var defaultTailSize = 3;
    var tailSize = defaultTailSize;
    var snakeTrail = [];
    var snakeHead = [];
    var snakeX = (snakeY = 10);

    // Amasya Elması
    var appleX = (appleY = 15);

    // Ekrana Çiz
    function draw() {

        // Yılanı sonraki pos'a (pozisyona) ilerlet  - move snake to next pos
        snakeX += nextX;
        snakeY += nextY;

        // Yılan Oyun Alanının Dışına Çıkarsa - Snake go to out of canvas
        if (snakeX < 0) {
            snakeX = gridSize - 1;
        }
        if (snakeX > gridSize - 1) {
            snakeX = 0;
        }

        if (snakeY < 0) {
            snakeY = gridSize - 1;
        }
        if (snakeY > gridSize - 1) {
            snakeY = 0;
        }

        //Yılan Elmayı Yakalarsa - Snake Eats The Apple
        if (snakeX == appleX && snakeY == appleY) {
            tailSize++;
            score++;
            appleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);
            appleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridSize);
        }

        //Background
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Draw Snake
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        drwhd.fillStyle = "blue";
        for (var i = 0; i < snakeTrail.length; i++) {
            ctx.fillRect(
                snakeTrail[i].x * tileSize,
                snakeTrail[i].y * tileSize,
                tileSize,
                tileSize
            );

            drwhd.fillRect(
                snakeHead[0].x * tileSize,
                snakeHead[0].y * tileSize,
                tileSize,
                tileSize
            );

            //Yılan Kendine Çarparsa - Snake Hit Himself
            if (snakeTrail[i].x == snakeX && snakeTrail[i].y == snakeY) {
                tailSize = defaultTailSize;
                score = 0;
            }
            if (highScore < score) {
                highScore = score;
            }

        }

        // Amasya Elmasını Boya :D - Paint Apple
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(appleX * tileSize, appleY * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);

        //set snake trail
        snakeTrail.push({
            x: snakeX,
            y: snakeY
        });

        snakeHead.push({
            x: snakeX,
            y: snakeY
        });

        while (snakeTrail.length > tailSize) {
            snakeTrail.shift();
            snakeHead.shift();
        }

        //PUANI YAZDIR 
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText("Skor : " + score, 25, 25);
        ctx.fillText("En Yüksek :" + highScore, 25, 45);
    }

    // tuşlar
    function keyDownEvent(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 87 && nextY != 1) {
            nextX = 0;
            nextY = -1;
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 83 && nextY != -1) {
            nextX = 0;
            nextY = 1;
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 68 && nextX != -1) {
            nextX = 1;
            nextY = 0;
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 65 && nextX != 1) {
            nextX = -1;
            nextY = 0;
        }
    }

    var canvas, ctx;

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    drwhd = canvas.getContext("2d");

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownEvent);

    // her saniye X'i renderla 
    var x = 8;
    setInterval(draw, 1000 / x);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `ctx` and `drwhd` are the same canvas context, so you're setting the fill style of that same context twice...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  , So what will i do? I cant understand :/

Comment: To avoid complications do not separate the snake head and trail. Put both in on collection `Snake`. And in for loop `if(i===0) ctx.fillStyle='white'; else ctx.fillStyle='blue'.`

Comment: Thank you all so much . That's SOLVED !! :)